# How to read object URI(JSON FILE) from json file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, api

I have a JSON FIle and In this JSON file there is an object URI and this URI contain a JSON file and I am trying to fetch data from URI JSON file but I could not I also attached my code and JSON file

```
class Details extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            question: null,
          };
    }




    componentDidMount(){
     const { match: { params } } = this.props;

       axios.get(params.uri).then((res)=>{
         const question = res.data[0]['uri'];
         axios.get(question).then((qRes) => {
           console.log(qRes); //will return the data from the second uri
         })
         console.log(question);
         this.setState({ question });
       })

   }
```

This is JSON data where Object URI contains a JSON File So I want to fetch data from URI JSON file.

```
[
  {
    "id": 59413,
    "thumbnail": {
      "id": "60255",
      "title": "dornoch-castle-whisky-bar",
      "alt": "dornoch-castle-whisky-bar",
      "url": "https://media-magazine.trivago.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/23144800/dornoch-castle-whisky-bar.jpg",
      "courtesy": "",
      "position": "center"
    },
    "thumbnail_url": "https://media-magazine.trivago.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/23144800/dornoch-castle-whisky-bar.jpg",
    "slug": "dornoch-castle-scotland-whisky",
    "uri": "http://trivago-magazine-work-sample-server.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dornoch-castle-scotland-whisky.json",
    "title": "Dornoch Castle: A Whisky Tasting at One of the World's Most Popular Hotel Bars",
    "card_title": "Whisky Tasting at Dornoch Castle in the Scottish Highlands",
    "show_publish_date": false,
    "date": "January 29th, 2019",
    "newsletter_popup": false,
    "newsletter_popup_header_image": false,
    "taxonomies": {
      "destinations": [
        {
          "name": "Europe",
          "uri": "/destination/international/europe",
          "slug": "europe",
          "term_id": 1384
        }
      ],
      "themes": [],
      "types": [
        {
          "name": "Nature",
          "uri": "/type/nature",
          "slug": "nature",
          "term_id": 1380
        }
      ]
    },
    "excerpt": "Dornoch Castle has amassed a whisky collection unlike most any other in the world. trivago Magazine Editor, Joe Baur, signs up for their whisky tasting. Video below."
  },
```

And This is console image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCwtR.png)

Answer (score 0):

You only can load data from a different domain if the response headers from the server, indicating that the resource is allowed to be accessed by other websites directly. Otherwise, you may create a proxy on your server to download the data.